# Use syntactically invalid names in j data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with column names that are not valid R names

```
DT = data.table(a = c(1, 2), `0b` = c(4, 5))
```

And I want to use something like this

```
my_column <- "0b"
DT[, mean(eval(parse(text = my_column)))]
```

but I get an error

```
Error in parse(text = my_column) : <text>:1:2: unexpected symbol
1: 0b
     ^
```

Is there any way how I can do it, i.e. use non valid column name as a variable inside j?

Comment: You don't need `eval(parse(`...  Try  `DT[, mean(.SD[[1L]]),.SDcols=my_column]` or just `mean(DT[[my_column]])`

Comment: You don't want ``DT[,mean(`0b`)] ``?

Comment: Oh, haven't thought this way. Great, thank you @akrun

Comment: Use akrun's suggestion or if you want to keep the dreaded parsey way ``DT[, mean(eval(parse(text= sprintf("`%s`", my_column))))]``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can either specify the column in `.SDcols` and get the `mean` using `.SD`

```
DT[, mean(.SD[[1L]]),.SDcols=my_column]
```

Or we can subset the column using `[[` and then get the `mean`.

```
mean(DT[[my_column]])
```

Comment: `.SD[[1L]]` specifies what?

Comment: @AvinashRaj The usual syntax would be `DT[, lapply(.SD, mean),.SDcols=my_column]`, if there are multiple columns.  But, here there is only a single column, and `mean` works with a `vector` and not on a data.frame or `list`.  Here, I am converting the single column to a vector by doing that.  For example `mean(data.frame(v1=1:10))
#[1] NA` and `mean(data.frame(v1=1:10)[[1L]])`

Comment: @AvinashRaj `.SD` means `Subset of Data.table`.  You can also check the difference in output `DT[, .SD, .SDcols=my_column]` and `DT[, .SD[[1L]], .SDcols=my_column]`

Comment: Oh, now I understand. think `DT[, .SD[[1]], .SDcols=my_column]` and `DT[, .SD[[1L]], .SDcols=my_column]` does the same job then why you use `L` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj in that case thy do the same job. I prefer to use integers `L` explicitly when it is conceptually valid, like in above example of taking `.SD` element by it's index. It enhance readability of code.

Answer (score 5):

As you specified in declaring your example, using backticks (`) is a common way to handle strange column names:

```
DT[ , mean(`0b`)]
```

Though `get` also works:

```
DT[ , mean(get("0b"))]
```

We can also do it the `data.frame` way

```
sapply(DT[ , "0b"], mean)
```

Though you may just want to `setnames` to get rid of the pesky column names altogether (by reference)

```
setnames(DT, "0b", "something_digestible")
```

Answer (score 5):

In R, syntactically invalid names need back-ticks in order to be evaluated. Although `.SDcols` is probably the proper way to go, you can use `as.name()` or `as.symbol()` to turn the character `my_column` into a back-ticked name.

```
DT[, mean(eval(as.name(my_column)))]
# [1] 4.5
```

Or a bit more clunky way would be to do

```
with(DT, do.call(mean, list(as.name(my_column))))
# [1] 4.5
```

Comment: @kismsu `eval(as.name(` is the closest you can get to `eval(parse(`.